# How can i make my Networking class generic in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Here i am extracting data as **DataModel**. But i want to make this class generic and pass the model myself so that i can use it to parse data from multiple API's. Can Anyone Help?

```swift
import Foundation

struct NetworkManager {
    func fetchData(url : String, completion : @escaping (DataModel?) -> ()) {
        print("Neeraj here")
        let sessionURL = URL(string: url)
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: sessionURL!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let safeData = data {
                    if let parsedData = self.parseData(data : safeData) {
                        print("got data")
                        completion(parsedData)
                    }
                    else {
                        debugPrint("failed to fetch data")
                        completion(nil)
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                print("error in data task is \(String(describing: error))")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
        
    }
    
    func parseData(data : Data) -> DataModel? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(DataModel.self, from: data)
            return decodedData
        } catch {
            print("error while parsing data \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `DataModel` is `Codable`, so you might need that for the generic part. But did you try anything? You have quite a simple generic code. If you need it, you can first put the `parseData` code inside the fetch one, and later once you understood the generic, put it again in another method.

Comment: i am not asking about using generics but i was asking how can i pass dataModel myself so as to handle multiple API's from this single class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the convenient `Result` type you can write a quite tiny generic method, it returns the decoded type on success and any error on failure

```
func fetchData<T: Decodable>(urlString: String, completion: @escaping (Result<T,Error>) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return } // or throw an error
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
        if let error = error { completion(.failure(error)); return }
        completion( Result{ try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data!) })
    }.resume()
}
```

Note: Force unwrapping `data!` is 100% safe if no error occurs

---

Be aware that you have to specify the concrete type when you are going to call the method

```
fetchData(urlString: "https://example.com/api") { (result : Result<MyModel,Error>) in
    switch result {
        case .success(let model): print(model)
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that this is a more elegant approach, because it allows you to have access to the errors that may occur from the network, the OS or the decoding process. Also, I didn't know that `init(catching:)` initializer of `Result` existed :) although I tend to map all errors to a custom error type.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a generic type constraint (called `Model`) which conforms `Decodable` like below:

```swift
struct NetworkManager {

    func fetchData<Model: Decodable>(url : String, completion : @escaping (Model?) -> ()) {
        let sessionURL = URL(string: url)
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: sessionURL!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let safeData = data {
                    do {
                        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Model.self, from: safeData)
                        completion(decodedData)
                    } catch {
                        print("error while parsing data \(error)")
                    }
                } else {
                    debugPrint("failed to fetch data")
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
            else {
                print("error in data task is \(String(describing: error))")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

### Usage

```swift
struct SampleModel: Decodable {
    let name: String
}

NetworkManager().fetchData(url: "") { (data: SampleModel?) in
    print(data)
}
```

Comment: How shall i call it earlier i was calling it like self.networkManager.fetchData(url: url) { (data) in

Comment: it is giving "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred" error

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check @NeerajGupta

Comment: Thanks For your help @sonie. I got it, i can use generics to do the task.

Comment: why do you use struct not class?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a generic function to fetch data like this one :

```
    func fetchGenericData<T: Decodable>(urlString: String, completion: @escaping (T) -> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, resp, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to fetch data:", err)
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            do {
                let obj = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                completion(obj)
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Failed to decode json:", jsonErr)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

I suppose that you have a data model, if you have not, you should create for your every object. Also by using a dummy URL i will make a request and fetch the JSON includes some users name and ids with JSON format.
Let`s define a data model for this:

```
struct StackUser: Decodable {
      let id: Int
      let name: String
  }

fetchGenericData(urlString: "https://api.stackoverexample.com/stackusers") { (stackUsers: [StackUser]) in
     stackUsers.forEach({print($0.name)})
}
```

Finally you will be parse the data and prints like this:

```
Rob
Matt
Vadian
```

Comment: Thanks for your help too @zeytin. I see you are using guards and i like your approach. Such a clean code you had written.